# ReactJS: How to display an child component error in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I would like to display an error message on my parent react component if an error occurs on a child element.

In this case an error would be a catch of a apollo mutation call for example as you can see in the GrandChild component.

Of course I could create a function in the parent component which sets a state value for the error and pass the function down to every child, grandchild and so on.
But as my structure is a bit complicated it would mean a lot of work. That's why I thought of using react error boundaries. But is this the correct use case?

As I'm using nextJS, every `throw Error` will display an error stacktrace in development mode, so it is impossible to display the error as a message

**Parent.js**

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      { /* if there is an error in any child component, it should be displayed here */
        this.props.error &&
        <Message>{error}</Message>
      }
      <Child {...props} />
    )
  }
}
```

**GrandChild.js**

```
class GrandChild extends Component {
  doAnything () {
    return this.props.assumeToFail({
      variables: { id: '123' }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error) // <-- this error should be given back to parent
      throw new Error('fail') // <-- should I throw the error or call a custom function?
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.doAnything().bind(this)}>anything</Button>
    )
  }
}

export default graphql(exampleMutation, { name: 'assumeToFail' })(GrandChild)
```

To use the error boundaries in my nextJS application I just have to add

**_app.js**

```
class MyApp extends App {
  componentDidCatch (error, errorInfo) {
    console.log('CUSTOM ERROR HANDLING', error)
    // How do I get the error down to 'Component' in render()?
    super.componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo)
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps, apolloClient } = this.props
    return <Container>
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Container>
  }
}
```

to my *_app.js* file. But I'm not sure if this is the way to go... and I don't know how to get the error down to the `Component`.

Comment: See `componentDidCatch` https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

Comment: @quirimmo Please have a look at the updated post: I'm using `componentDidCatch` in my nextJS app, but this causes always to display a stacktrace in dev mode, so I can't display the error in the component.

Comment: Read the link I shared. They talk about that too

Comment: @quirimmo In nextJS the stacktrace is not only passed to the console, but also displayed on screen. So in case of an error, the application isn't visible anymore (in dev mode)

Comment: `componentDidCatch` is only part of it, you also need to create an error boundary component that implements `componentDidCatch` so it can return some error state and based on that return a fallback component. See https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html . Be aware that it does dump a fullscreen stack trace "modal", there's an "X" in the upper right to close it and get back to your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The best way to implement this is by using react state management like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [fluxible](https://fluxible.io/).
   If you are using react state management, then you can call the action by dispatch the message from the `child.js` and connect to redux store in the `parent.js` to get the error message easily.
2. If you decide to use function like what you have described, you can pass a function to the children and let the children call that function.

**Parent.js**

```js
export class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    error: null,
  }

  render () {
    return (
      { /* if there is an error in any child component, it should be displayed here */
        this.state.error &&
        <Message>{this.state.error}</Message>
      }
      <Child
        {...props}
        defineError={(errMsg) => setState({ error: errMsg })}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

**GrandChild.js**

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class GrandChild extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    defineError: PropTypes.func,    
  }

  doAnything () {
    return this.props.assumeToFail({
      variables: { id: '123' }
    }).catch(error => {
      this.props.defineError(error);
      console.error(error) // <-- this error should be given back to parent
      throw new Error('fail') // <-- should I throw the error or call a custom function?
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.doAnything().bind(this)}>anything</Button>
    )
  }
}

export default graphql(exampleMutation, { name: 'assumeToFail' })(GrandChild)
```

Comment: React provides a default way to handle errors from *any* rendered descendant (not just direct children) through error boundaries, which also gives you the opportunity to make updates to any redux or app state being used if needed, through lifecycle functions.  No need to re-invent the wheel.  React's error boundaries work similar to `try/catch` blocks where the nearest boundary (catch) up the chain handles the error.